# I want to display the products that are on my companies website in a custom order and I am not quite sure if this is correct

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

just to add sorry if my wording/grammar is terrible I do suffer from dyslexia.
So I have never actually done any web design, so all I have really learned is through the internet and from what I have figured out on my own. So I was just wondering if I was on the right track or if I am going in the completely wrong way.

So to give some background on what I want to do. I have added quite a few products around 1-1.5k and while I have added them, the order seems to be quite random. looking into it I find out the reason for that. That it has to deal with menu order, then alphabetical. however, the main problem, is if I were to just use menu order if I add one more product it will ruin the order. Also taking into account my boss wants it in a specific order. So I have been trying to read up on how to use the order by and other things to order by specific Attributes/categories. however, since I have never learned web design or PHP, or even WordPress I am struggling quite hard.

This is the code I have come up with and tried to make. Sorry if its a bit messy, trying my best.

```html
<?php
 
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 'bbqs-by-brand,blackstone,bull-grills,char-broil,coyote-grills,crown-verity,dcs,delta-heat,green-mountain-grills,jackson-grills,louisiana-grills,napoleon,other,primo,saber-grills,zgril') );
 
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
                'key'     => 'bbqs-by-brand',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'napoleon',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'jackson-grills',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'saber-grills',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
         array(
                'key'     => 'bull-grills',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
         array(
                'key'     => 'delta-heat',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
         array(
                'key'     => 'coyote-grills',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
         array(
                'key'     => 'dcs',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'green-mountain-grills',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'louisiana-grills',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'zgril',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'primo',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'blackstone',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'char-broil',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        array(
                'key'     => 'other',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
    ),
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: What do you want the posts to be ordered by? displaying all posts, each category after another, and the posts inside the category alphabetically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @rank I want to display all posts, ordering them by a single category then attributes, as an example. I want to order category order to be napoleon, then Jackson, then saber, then bull grills and so on. But between these categories. I want to add attributes like the model of BBQ. So if it's a rouge model or which ever, I want to be able to order it by that. So I want lets say to order by category, model of BBQ, then menu order.

Hopefully this answers your question
thanks 
deathspike123.